# Exclusive Disjunction

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g

I have a table with product prices. There are two price types: A = offer price, B = standard price. Example:

```
 product_id  |  price  |  price_type
-------------------------------------
 001         |  0.99   |  A
 001         |  1.49   |  B
```

I'm looking for a SELECT-statement that returns

- the standard price (type B), if there's no offer price (type A) for this product,
- the offer price (type A) whenever the product has a price of type A (disregarded if a price of type B is maintained or not).

For my example data above the statement has to return the offer price = **0.99** = type A.

Comment: hv u tried something?plz don't ask us to do ur homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a left join.  I am assuming that you will at least always have a standard price row for a product.

```
select p1.product_id,
       coalesce(p2.price, p1.price) as price
  from product_prices p1
  left join product_prices p2
    on p2.product_id = p1.product_id
   and p2.price_type = 'A'
 where p1.price_type = 'B'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could left join two queries on the table and use `coalesce` to determine if there's an offer or not:

```
SELECT    b.product_id, COALESCE(a.price, b.price)
FROM      (SELECT product_id, price
           FROM   products
           WHERE  price_type = 'B') b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, price
           FROM   products
           WHERE  price_type = 'A') a ON a.product_id = b.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it could be done by:

select * 
   from product 
   where price_type in (select min(price_type) 
   from product group by product_id);

Comment: This really only works with the 2 rows that OP posted. As soon as you add more data with more product ids, this will not work.

Comment: You are right about this. As I said, it based on OP's example.